# How to fix the Col spacing in the following modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i have problem in spacing the area between sections and the 2 buttons like the other around it

iam trying to add a space between sections and 2 buttons with keeping the shape same couldnot do it without destroying the button shapes that what i have atm

the form in the git in index from 187 to 258 the section code from 223 234
https://github.com/ahmedabdo97/bootstrap4

```
<div class="form-group row col-12">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="col-12 col-md-3 mr-auto col-form-label">Sections</label>
        <label class="btn btn-success active  col-md-5">
        <input type="radio" name="non-smoking" id="non-smoking" autocomplete="off" checked> Non-Smoking
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-danger col-md-4">
        <input type="radio" name="smoking" id="smoking" autocomplete="off"> Smoking
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

the actual result
https://github.com/ahmedabdo97/bootstrap4/blob/master/Screenshot_1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tags are not properly organized. Try to add

```
<label class="btn btn-success active  col-md-5">
  <input type="radio" name="non-smoking" id="non-smoking" autocomplete="off" checked> Non-Smoking
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-danger col-md-4">
   <input type="radio" name="smoking" id="smoking" autocomplete="off"> Smoking
</label>
```

in a Div Tag and add .ml-2 to it